# React Hook "useSelector" is called in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I cannot figure out what going on with "useSelector" I need little help, please.

**ERROR**

> React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "render_user" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

```
class Navigationbar extends Component {

  onLogoutClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logoutUser(); //this.props.
  };

  render() {
      const render_user = () => {

        const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth); Error Message is here
        //More Code Here
      );
    };
  }
```

```
Navigationbar.propTypes = {
  logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser }
)(Navigationbar);
```

Comment: Looks like it's part of [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector). What error message are you getting?

Comment: This is crazy - are you using a redux hook in a class-based component that is already wrapped in connect?

Comment: This is ok, you are just getting started, suggest you read this (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). insted of `class Navigationbar extends Component` write `function Navigationbar () {
  ...
  return (
    <div>Hii</div>
  );
}`.
About useSelector it is kind of mapStateToProps if it will help you to understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you violated the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

> - Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
> - Only Call Hooks from React Functions

**Violations**:

1. `useSelector()` is not called in top-level. It is called in `render_user()` in `render()` (i.e nested function).
2. `useSelector()` is part of a class component, `Navigationbar`

You can extract a component to follow the rules of hooks and make use of `useSelector`:

```
function User() { // Rule 2: call hooks in function component
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth); // Rule 1: call hooks in top-level
  return <>{auth}</>
}

class Navigationbar extends Component {

  render_user() {
    if (props.authenticated) {
      return <User />
    }
    // not yet authenticated
    // do something else
  }

  render() {
    return <>{this.render_user()}</>
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Joseph, I forgot to show my whole code but the problems render_user() not was working fine. Here full code playground that shows full display of the Navbar. https://playcode.io/451473?tabs=script.js,preview,console

Comment: How can use if and else statement inside of an ```render_user()```

Comment: HEy @bpdg, modified slightly `render_user()`. It's just a function so you can freely add any conditional logic and use `props` or `state`.

Comment: Okay Thanks Joseph D

Answer (score 9):

If you are using TypeScript and (obviously) a functional component. Make sure your component name begins with a capital letter and not a lowercase letter.

Comment: Valid for js as well!

Answer (score 1):

useSelector is new hook that is added by react-redux after the addition of new **Hooks API** to react.

These hooks can only be used in **function** component

Answer (score 1):

## Solution for those who working with hook functional component

All `React component` names must start with a capital letter.

If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated like a built-in element like a `<div>` or a `<span>` . This is because of the way `JSX` works. In `JSX`, rendering a component that begins with a lowercase letter compiles down to React.