# Why I face with "... which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function" when I use React Hook in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I am trying to convert a react project from javascript to TypeScript. The project is created with CRA `--typescript`. I am using redux-saga in it. I don't have ts compile errors but I face with a runtime error.

I have already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764122/react-hook-useselector-is-called-in-function) and a few others and I think I am not violating the mentioned rules.

```js
import { IEventDto } from "dtos/event";
import React, { Dispatch, memo, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import { useInjectReducer, useInjectSaga } from "utilities";
import { IGlobalState } from "utilities/iState";
import { loadNearByEvents } from "./actions";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import saga from "./saga";
import { selectEvents } from "./selector";

interface IProps {
    events: IEventDto[];
}

interface IDispatches {
    loadEvents: () => void;
}

// I also tested it with normall function instead of arrow function.
// function homePage(props: IProps & IDispatches): JSX.Element {
const homePage: React.FC<IProps & IDispatches> = (props) => {
    useInjectReducer({ key: "home", reducer });
    useInjectSaga({ key: "home", saga });

    // here is the issue
    useEffect(() => {
        props.loadEvents();
    }, []);

    return (<div>
        <h2>This is the home page</h2>
        {props.events.map((event) => (<div>{event.title}</div>))}
    </div>);
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector<IGlobalState, IProps>({
    events: selectEvents(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<any>): IDispatches {
    return {
        loadEvents: () => dispatch(loadNearByEvents()),
    };
}

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
);

const HomePage = compose<React.FC>(
    withConnect,
    memo,
)(homePage);

export { HomePage };
```

The error message is:

```
Line 23:5:  React Hook "useInjectReducer" is called in function "homePage: React.FC<IProps & IDispatches>" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
Line 24:5:  React Hook "useInjectSaga" is called in function "homePage: React.FC<IProps & IDispatches>" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function     react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
Line 26:5:  React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "homePage: React.FC<IProps & IDispatches>" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function         react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

The `inject` methods are custom react hook functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, because it detects that `homePage` can never be used as a Component - React components begin with an uppercase letter. Lowercase would lead to html elements with that name to be created and your component would be ignored by React.

Of course, you wrap it later but your linter does not take that into account. So give it a different name with an uppercase first letter.